# must worker nodes have static IPs?

Tags: kubernetes, k3s, flannel

I'm facing [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75518931/how-to-approach-flannel-malfunction-misconfiguration) with  pods on worker nodes responding http requests - and it is not Traefik's or the application's fault. Everything works on the master nodes with these settings and deployment.

I'm wondering: Do k3s worker nodes require static IP addresses and a FQDN (not just a unique hostname) when added to a k3s cluster?

Comment: what's the issue ? you are facing why you are looking for static IP and error or issue you are facing ?

Comment: @HarshManvar I've added the link to the specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, worker nodes must have fixed IPs so that the kube-proxy can pick up on deployments. I don't know why that should be the mandatory. There is a k3s client (kublet, kube-proxy) installed on the client with a dynamic IP. That client could easily inform the K3s master nodes. I think that is a design flaw. Anyhow, it is that way: **Kubernetes worker nodes require a fixed IP**.